# Writing a function as sum of even and odd functions requires continuity?

Tags: real-analysis

Is continuity a requirement for a function to be decomposed into the sum of an even and odd component? I thought you can do that with any function.

Answer (score 1):

You can always do it. If $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ is any function (doesn't have to be continuous), then
\begin{align}
f_E(x):=\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2} \quad \text{and}\quad f_O(x):=\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}
\end{align}
are even and odd respectively, and $f=f_E+f_O$. Furthermore, this decomposition is unique.